Cannot connect to local minio instance using S3 Browser
I have setup a Minio server on my local network. It only has access via http on the local network configured. I am able to connect to this instance using both the CLI mc command and using a test Python application which uses the boto3 library.
However, I cannot connect using the Windows application S3 Browser.
When I try to connect, I see the following exception.
Unable to perform requested action:

Error occured during getting buckets list
System.Net.WebException

Server Response:
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send.


I have configured the account as type "S3 Compatiable Storage". The REST endpoint is set to 192.168.0.x:9000. I tried to enter http://192.168.0.x:9000 here, however this appears to just default back to the address without a http:// prefix.

I must be very stupid because I spent hours on this yesterday without realizing there is a checkbutton at the bottom of the Edit Account window which is labeled

"Use secure transfer (SSL/TLS)

If you want to use http instead of https this should be turned off.
I turned it off, and now it works fine.
I guess I was looking for something related to http/https so missed this option at the bottom.

